# Docker: docker-compose for bundling meteor app not working.. (npm errors)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor, npm, docker-compose

Anyone able to help me with this problem? I am currently trying to bundle my meteor app via docker-compose and I keep getting npm errors back and forth. I have finally gotten to the last build step in my Dockerfile called by my docker-compose.yml file, but I'm getting lots of errors.. All files, including the package.json, are clearly visible in the app directory so there is no reason for it being, among others, hidden from the install.

here is my dockerfile and following that are the errors:

---

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

# Install NodeJS from Node-Source repo (node 0.10.48).
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Add your app on /Home and install NPM modules. And clean the cache.
RUN mkdir /home/app
COPY app.tar.gz /tmp/app.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxf /tmp/app.tar.gz -C /home/app
RUN apt-get install -y python
RUN cd /home/app/bundle/programs/server

RUN apt-get update
RUN npm install
#RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Expose port 80, but remember to use PORT=80
EXPOSE 80

# Run the app
WORKDIR /home/app
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

---

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 34
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install node in your Dockerfile. Use a Node docker image as your base image. https://hub.docker.com/r/_/node/

Then install additional dependencies you have such as python. Use `WORKDIR` docker directive and then copy your files into the `WORKDIR`.

```
FROM node:wheezy

RUN mkdir /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY app.tar.gz .
RUN tar -zxf app.tar.gz && npm install && apt-get update && apt-get install -y python && cd bundle/programs/server && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# Expose port 80, but remember to use PORT=80
EXPOSE 80

# Run the app
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!! I've now gotten past the first errors but the build got to the last step and returned this : ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"meteor\": executable file not found in $PATH"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: Based on `"exec: \"meteor\": executable file not found in $PATH`. My guess is that you are not running the `CMD` from the correct location. Maybe add a line after `expose 80` to give yourself some information. `RUN ls -lha` or `RUN echo $PWD`. I think that your app needs to be executed from `/home/app`.